# Live update message system using php js msyql

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, messaging

Okay guys, I'm trying to integrate a facebook-like messaging system into my web application. I can't post the link unfortunately because it requires login.

I have the database with a conversation table, a messages table, and the html page which calls all the messages based on the given conversation id. I also have a text area and submit button for sending a new message and adding it to the database.

Now I've heard two different methods..

1. That I should have javascript check for updates every second or so to see new messages, and update with ajax. Would this put too much strain on a server?

or.

2. To use a frame work like node.js. This method makes very little sense to me as I really don't understand requests very well.

So stack overflow, which method (or neither) would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling is resource-heavy.  You should consider something like WebSockets.

With WebSockets, you basically will have the client chat user apps subscribe the to the WebSocket, and then the back end server application would notify them when they should check for updates, or just push the new message updates out to them right over the WebSocket connection.

Here is a [demo chat application](http://socketo.me/demo) you can look at.  Here's the [WebSocket website](https://www.websocket.org/).

Comment: he's right, you need something like websockets otherwise it would be too much; js or ajax would have too much of a heavy load. and you're supposed to use websockets when creating chats or real-time commenting system that constantly checks for updates.